# add hyphen after every fourth character in a string seperated by comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as `1111111111,2222222222,333333333,....`

I want to modify it as `1111-111111,2222-222222,3333-33333,....`

the regex I am using is this..

```
var num = '1111111111,2222222222,333333333,....'; 
var newNum = num.toString().match(/.{4}/g).join('-');
```

this add hyphen after every fourth character but **I am unable to reset when comma is found**.

Comment: `.replace(/\b(\d{4})/g, '$&-')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\b\d{4}
```

with replacement `$&-`

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/86gchj/3)

```js
var num = '1111111111,2222222222,333333333,....'; 
console.log(num.replace(/\b\d{4}/g, "$&-"));
```

Comment: There is no point wrapping the whole pattern with a capturing group if you need to refer to it from the replacement pattern. In JS, there is a `$&` replacement backreference right for this purpose (edited the post to show how to use it).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks a lot I didn't know that ;-) so it is very similar to the `\&` in `sed s/.../.../` search and replace command right?

Comment: Yes, same as `&` in sed or vim, and as `$0` in Java, PHP. `$&` also works in .NET and Boost. In Python `re`, `\g<0>` can only be used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks! `\g<0>` looks really like a backreference to a named capturing group!

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
let str = '1111111111,2222222222,333333333';

let res = str.split(",").map(s => s.slice(0,4) + "-" + s.slice(4, s.length-1)).join(",");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `split()` and `substr()` to get that:

```js
var str = '1111111111,2222222222,333333333';
var res =[];
str.split(',').forEach((item)=>{
   res.push(item.substr(0,4)+'-'+item.substr(4,item.length));
});
console.log(res);
```